# Does deletion of a SNS platform application, delete all registered endpoints?

Tags: amazon-sns

I am trying to provision a FCM SNS Platform Application using terraform. Then I create end-points for my mobile devices using boto3 python library. I would like to if my platform application is destroyed accidentally by terraform, then are all my corresponding endpoints deleted to or are will I be left with orphan endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All application endpoints are deleted when the associated platform application is deleted.